# combinations of black and red balls

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have this problem which I do not seem to be able to get my head around, sorry.

I have a total of $N$ balls: some are black and some are red. The number of black balls is, say, $B$. I want to consider combinations of these $N$ balls, and each combination is to have size, say, $m$. Thus, I have $\binom{N}{m}$ of these combinations.

I need to know how many of these combinations contain at least $P$ black balls. Any help will be very gratefully acknowledged.

EDIT HERE

Following on, I should have mentioned that: $P$ is definitely smaller than $m$ and $B$. Conversely, I cannot know which one is smaller between $B$ and $m$, I am working under the assumption that I cannot "open the box" and check how many balls $B$ there are.

Comment: mention properly which one of $p,m,B$ is greater and which is less,this affects the answer,it would be complicated to discuss all cases.

Comment: thank you so much, I have edited the question - but your answer below is really helpful and I wish to thank you for it

Answer (score 2):

$^BC_p.^{N-B}C_{m-p}+^BC_{p+1}.^{N-B}C_{m-p-1}+\dots+^BC_m.^{N-B}C_{0}$ assuming $B>m$.One thing to be pointed out is that which one among $B,m,p$ etc is greater and which one is less or else it would become complicated to discuss all cases.

Comment: You can just write it as $\sum_{k=P}^{\infty}\binom{B}{k}\binom{N-B}{m-k}$ under the convention that $\binom{r}{s}=0$ if $s\notin\{0,\dots,r\}$. This convention "catches" all cases and makes further description concerning $B,m,P$ redundant.

Comment: Thanks,this provides a compact form.

Comment: thank you so much, really appreciated and very nice and compact